# How to select the first word of every line and attribute it to an array in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I would like to create a bash script that selects the first word of each line from a text file before the ":" character, and outputs it in an array (1 slot for 1 line).

Right now I have this:

```
while read p; 
do
  arr+=$p | sed -r 's///'
done <test.txt
```

and I can't figure out what to put in the condition of the sed.

I have this regexep :

```
/^([^:])+/gm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a subshell and sed, just use parameter expansion:

```
while read p ; do
  arr+=( "${p%%:*}" )
done < test.txt
```

It might be faster to remove all the substrings in one command

```
while read p ; do
    arr+=("$p")
done < test.txt
arr=("${arr[@]%%:*}")
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this responce, I have another question :
I would like to use every element from the array "arr" and use them in a sed to repalce them if found in a text file has such :

for i in "${arr[@]"
fo
sed -r 's/$i/USERNAME/g' /../var/log/auth.log > /../root/sword-anon-connections.log
done

but I think there is a problem with the variable

Comment: To ask a new question, create a new question. Also, variables aren't expanded in single quotes.

Comment: In bash 4.0+, the loop could be simplified to: `<infile readarray -t arr`

Answer (score 0):

With `bash` 4 or later, you may use `readarray` to read directly into an array:

```
readarray -t arr < <( awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }' file.in )
```

The `awk` code runs in a process substitution and provides the data. It simply extracts the first field of each `:`-delimited line.

Example with `file.in` as

```
roses are:red
violets:are blue
sugar is:sweet and
so:are
you:.
```

```
$ readarray -t arr < <( awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }' file.in )
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${arr[@]}"
"roses are"
"violets"
"sugar is"
"so"
"you"
```